# Rails Dropdown has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, has-many-through, model-associations

I can't save the id's in the join table (document_configuration).

I have tree models:

document.rb

```
belongs_to :languages
has_many :document_configurations
has_many :document_catalogs, through: :document_configurations

accepts_nested_attributes_for :document_catalogs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :document_configurations
```

document_catalog.rb

```
has_many :document_configurations
has_many :documents, through: :document_configurations
```

document_configuration.rb

```
belongs_to :document
belongs_to :document_catalog
```

So, I want to get a list of all `document_catalog` in my `document_form` So, when I create a new document I can include the corresponding catalog.

This is my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.select :document_catalog_ids, DocumentCatalog.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}%>
</div>
```

Is listing the catalogs as I want.

This is my controller:

```
def new
 @document = Document.new
 @document.document_catalogs.build
end

def document_params
  params.require(:document).permit(:name, :description, :document_file,
  :language_id, {:document_catalog_ids=>[]}) #I tried this too: :document_catalog_ids=>[] without the {}
end
```

I'm just getting this error: `Unpermitted parameter: document_catalog_ids` **and I really need to save the** `document_id` and `document_catalog_id` in `document_configuration` model.

Another thing is: **I need to add anything else in my create, update and destroy methods?**

Comment: The best way to figure out what is going wrong is to check what the actual params are that are coming through to your controller. You can do that eg by putting `puts params.inspect` as the first line of `def document_params` and then run the action and check the output in the server-window. Usually this will let you see what it is you're missing (eg nesting levels).

Comment: Your join table is breaking rails convention.  Rails expects the name of the join table to always be in lexical order so try changing the table name to "configuration_documents" and see if that straightens it out.  Checkout the docs here and look at section 3.3.2   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: Thank you both. I checek the displaying the params and then I changed the model name. I still have the issue in this way, so I changed the logic i little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling of Unpermitted Keys

By default parameter keys that are not explicitly permitted will be logged in the development and test environment. In other environments these parameters will simply be filtered out and ignored.

Additionally, this behaviour can be changed by changing the `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters` property in your environment files. If set to `:log` the unpermitted attributes will be logged, if set to `:raise` an exception will be raised.

Found this in a documentation from GitHub : https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#handling-of-unpermitted-keys

Comment: Thank you @astelvidaxror I'm trying a different approach. However, thanks to your comment I lerned a new couple of things.